# homework about homomorphisms : find all the homomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, continuous-homomorphisms

1. Find all the continuous  homomorphisms  $T:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
2. Find all the  homomorphisms  $T:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ (complex field) such that $T(x)=x$ for every $x$.

Any hints please?

Comment: Homomorphisms as what? Fields? Rings? Groups? Topological spaces?

Comment: If it were fields or rings or topological spaces, the continuity assumption in (1) would be redundant or pleonastic. So the most likely thing is *groups*, I suppose. - Also the OP should please check the exact formulation of (2) because as it stands it is more tan trivial.

Comment: Most likely is not a certainty. I am not sure how my comment is any less relevant. I think a simple clarification by the OP will resolve any questions. My mention of Topological spaces was not for (1) but (2). The point is the category in which one is working is crucial. As you pointed out, the identity is the function specified by the OP so that is the only possible choice.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, that's how the question is written in my homework, word by word. R and C are fields, so I think the  homomorphism is between fields, could it be anything else? I don't understand..

Comment: @Gartaa : What about the homomorphism $ f(z) =$ conjugate of $z$?

Comment: A group/ring homomorphism can also exist between fields.

Comment: I need to find  homomorphism that follows the rules of: T(X+Y)=T(X)+T(Y) , T(XY)= T(X)T(Y), T(1)=1. Is it clearer?

Comment: @Manasi: In that case, $T(x) \neq x$

Comment: Considering R as a field, it is a field homomorphism. So, it trivially satisfies the properties of a group/ring homomorphism(the vice-versa need not always be true).

Comment: I think $T(x)=x$ for $x \in R$.

Comment: can you help me in (2)

Comment: Oh ok.. I just checked it is for $C$. What is the point of this question they have already specified the answer then?

Comment: why do you think they specified the answer?

Comment: What do you think about $T(z) = z \forall z \in C $?Is that a field homomorphism?

Comment: I can only think of the identity  homomorphism

Comment: Now, they have asked you to find all field homomorphisms satisfying  a field homomorphism!

Comment: yes I need to find all of them

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11420/discussion-between-manasi-and-cnr)

Comment: Sorry, the chat did not work. If $f(z) = g(z) = z \forall z \in C$ then does it not mean that $f=g$? So,precisely they have spelt out the answer in the question...

Comment: do you mean f(z) = z is the  homomorphism ?

Comment: I want to add something I noticed right now, it is for every REAL x

Comment: @CnR : Can you show that f(z) = z is a homomorphism?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I just checked your profile. You are good at Math, why not engage in it seriously?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for first problem** Assuming your question will be **Field Isomorphism**

$f(1)=f(1\times 1)= [f(1)]^2\Rightarrow f(1)=?$

$f(n)=f(1+1+\dots+1\text { ntimes })=n\times f(1)=n\times 1=n\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

$f(0)=f(1+(-1))=f(1)+f(-1)=0\Rightarrow f(-1)=-f(1)$

$f(x)=x\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}$ (use $f(-1)=-f(1))$

$x={p\over q}\in\mathbb{Q},q\in\mathbb{N},p\in\mathbb{Z}$

$f(p)=p=f(qx)=f(x+x+\dots+x) \text { q times}=qf(x)=p\Rightarrow f(x)={p\over q}=x\forall x\in\mathbb{Q}$

Use Continuity of $f$ to Show $f(x)=x\forall x\in\mathbb{Q}^c$

so $f(x)=x\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Manasi Mahapatra Thank you

Comment: @Jonathan: This was for (1).

Comment: @Sade, as for the 2nd part, if $\mathbb{R}$ is fixed by $f$, then $f$ is uniquely determined by $f(i)$. But then, $f$ cannot just assume any value at $i$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It will only produce a group homomorphism! Oops!

Comment: @JonathanY. Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

Comment: I doubt that the question is about *field* homomorphisms as in that case the continuiuty assumption in (1) woiuld be redundant.